# If device is on, turn it off (and vice versa) | Multi-Step Routines | Alexa

Tags: smart-home, alexa, amazon-echo

How to run an Alexa routine that checks the current status of a device, and changes it?

Example:

```
If LivingRoomLamp is on
Then turn off LivingRoomLamp

If LivingRoomLamp is off
Then turn on LivingRoomLamp
```

The routine will be called via an external service (This part works). The issue is that I only want one “on/off” button with this service, not one “on” and one “off” button. For this to work, I need to check the status of the device, and then change it, all within the Alexa app.

Lastly, today is my first day using Alexa, I normally use the Google Assistant.